# Principles to draw a contour

Tags: python, drawing, contour

I want to know the principles to draw a contour, for example, which lib they use, I mean the most original one ,not matplotlib or opencv.

Like in matplotlib or opencv, they use what kind of method to draw a contour.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: What do you mean *"the most original one"*? What's wrong with `matplotlib`?

Comment: I guess he means he's interested in the algorithm, and not just using a library. Although drawing contours does not require much more beyond the ability to draw a line... if you have the list of points, just loop through the points, drawing a line between each pair. You can make them closed by making a line between the first and last points in the list. If you want them filled, then that's a different problem, which can be solved by [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

Comment: matplotlib is strong, sometimes I don't want that many functions, I only need a few of them. So that is why I asked how matplotlib works when it draws a contour. @MattDMo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) of `Opencv` mentioned this function implements the algorithm of:

```
    Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by 
Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985)
```

so you can read about this algorithm and discover the principles of draw a contour! and see the wiki link of `Suzuki-Kasami algorithm` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki-Kasami_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want!